# An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(java.lang.Class, java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question on the main part itself. Please post the script/code along with the difficulty you face. read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Structure, set the JDK location to JDK11 home path.